# How to prevent disposing a screen when using BottomNavigationBar in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a simple async function and I call this function in my initState. This function reads my Firebase Firestore database and I want to keep the amount of reads as low as possible. But when using a BottomNavigationBar, and navigating with body: _widgetOptions.elementAt(index), a screen gets disposed whenever is navigated to a new screen. When I return back to the original screen initState is called again and my data is being loaded again while this is not something I need or want.

Does anyone have a solution or tips?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a [global](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple) boolean variable in your [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider). Let say, `isCalled` is with the default value `false`. Then, you can check if `isCalled` is `false` before calling your method. And then, you can set it true after calling your method.

Comment: I make a lot of complex functions but couldn’t think of anythink like this.. lol, thanks a lot!